# What does V.C. mean here?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

This is a quote from Franz Schubert's diary, translated from German to English.

***Today I composed for money for the first time. Namely, a cantata for the name day of Professor Watteroth, words by Draexler. The fee is two florins. V.C.***

What I don't understand is the end of the quote, ***V.C.*** I looked up, but no definition seemed to be right when it is used in one's diary.

Does anybody have a clue?

Thank you.

(As a non-native English-speaker, I assumed this is about English language. If not, please let me know and I will delete it, immediately.)

Comment: [This alternative translation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uyCr828sf28C&pg=PA43&dq=%22a+cantata+for+the+name+day+of+Professor+Watteroth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO947Ste7kAhU3QUEAHcb-DBIQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20cantata%20for%20the%20name%20day%20of%20Professor%20Watteroth%22&f=false) of the same text says: *A cantata for the name day of Professor Watteroth. The honorarium **100 florins, Viennese currency**.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an unusual translation from German, not "use of English" as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers good find - I was about to go down the 'VG = viele grüße' route.

Comment: @marcellothearcane: Initially I was really puzzled by that ***two / 100** florins* difference, but now I'm thinking it's a credible OCR error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment:

> [This alternative translation](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uyCr828sf28C&pg=PA43&dq=%22a+cantata+for+the+name+day+of+Professor+Watteroth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO947Ste7kAhU3QUEAHcb-DBIQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20cantata%20for%20the%20name%20day%20of%20Professor%20Watteroth%22&f=false) of the same text says: A cantata for the name day of Professor Watteroth. The honorarium 100 florins, Viennese currency. – [FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers)